# Editing examples help div jumps around and lands on the left

Tags: bug, documentation

I clicked a little question mark to give me some help details about editing an example as shown:

[image]

But as soon as I expand the example the **Editing Examples** div flickers and ends up on the left side of my screen now:

[image]

Comment: In chrome but happens in IE as well (latest version of chrome, IE 11).